# How to create a datetime object from Year, Day, Hour and Minute columns (without month column) for 2 day data in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have data of the form,

|  | Year | Day | Hour | Minute | Field magnitude average, nT | Speed, km/s | AE-index, nT | SYM/H, nT | ASY/H, nT | PCN-index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017 | 250 | 0 | 0 | 8.27 | 390.6 | 117 | 42 | 20 | 2.00 |
| 1 | 2017 | 250 | 0 | 1 | 3.14 | 405.3 | 121 | 42 | 19 | 1.64 |
| 2 | 2017 | 250 | 0 | 2 | 3.86 | 434.2 | 124 | 42 | 21 | 1.72 |
| 3 | 2017 | 250 | 0 | 3 | 4.17 | 473.2 | 141 | 42 | 19 | 1.92 |
| 4 | 2017 | 250 | 0 | 4 | 3.43 | 497.0 | 107 | 41 | 19 | 1.70 |

How can I create a datetime object in Pandas using the Year, Day, Hour, Minute columns? What's the best approach?

I tried using

```
pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df.Year,day=df.Day,month=None))
```

which failed!

Also tried,

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df[["Year","Day","Hour","Minute"]]).dt.strftime('%d/%y %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge as a single string and use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with a custom format (`'%Y-%j-%H-%M'` for Year-DayOfYear-Hours-Minutes):

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']]
               .astype(str).agg('-'.join, axis=1), format='%Y-%j-%H-%M')
```

Output:

```
0   2017-09-07 00:00:00
1   2017-09-07 00:01:00
2   2017-09-07 00:02:00
3   2017-09-07 00:03:00
4   2017-09-07 00:04:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your Day column is JULIAN date, i.e. when 1st Jan is 1, then julian 250 is 9th July (in non leap year). If that is so, you can create additional column YJ to concatenate Year and Day and then apply datetime creation.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'Year':2017, 'Day':250, 'Hour':0, 'Minute':0, 'Data': 8.27},
        {'Year':2017, 'Day':250, 'Hour':1, 'Minute':0, 'Data': 3.14}]
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df['YJ'] = (df['Year'].apply(str)+df['Day'].apply(str)) #convert to string
df['DateTime'] = (df['YJ'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%j'))) #new column

#output: df.head()
```

|  | Year | Day | Hour | Minute | Data | YJ | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017 | 250 | 0 | 0 | 8.27 | 2017250 | 2017-09-07 |
| 1 | 2017 | 250 | 1 | 0 | 3.14 | 2017250 | 2017-09-07 |